# cannot add a report to CMC (Central Management Console) Business Objects

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

Hi  I am trying to add a report to the [cmc](/questions/tagged/cmc) but I am getting the following error.

```
Adding Crystal Report "customer details.rpt" failed. 
The server with kind rptappserver returned an error result. 

Failed to copy the report file to the report object. 
Refreshing the report object properties might have failed.

Failed to read data from report file D:\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\Data\CrystalReportsRasServer\temp\{E95CA1EF-E3A5-4590-93C0-0739194564AE}.rpt.

Reason: Unable to launch D:\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86\ReportAdd program to add report to the system.
```

The person  who was in charge of this before i joined has left and I have no one to ask.
Never used CMC before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below servers whether properly working or not:
1.Adaptive processing server
2.Crystal reports Processing server
3.Inputfile repository server
4.It can be issue of rights. The user you are using should have rights to add the report.

If possible restart CCM and check for servers successfully started and try to add the report.

Comment: Hi  I am logged in as adminstrator, so have full rights , but i  think it is because i have crystal 2011 and the BO is 2008 so I am downloading 2008 crystal now and i will see if that works

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem... Check servers are they running properly

Comment: Check that report properties may have "read only" option checked.. Its a blind guess though

Comment: HI I got it sorted, downloaded a version of crystal reports 2008 and saved the report through that and it worked a treat, Can I ask another question,  i have put a parameter into the report on customer code as i only want the report to run per customer, ( have a lot of customers) is parameters in schedule the only way to set this ? As non computer users will have to try access this report and  could find it troublesome.

Comment: First question is how non computer user will have access? Now if you run the report does parameter shows list of customer or customer need to enter manually to run the report. First case is typical where a single customer can view the data for other customer and second case is a bit similar to first one. If you want to provide security you need to do it at BO level. Let me know if you are looking for something else